# Do I really need to explicitely open a connection when ExecuteNonQuery()

Tags: c#, sql-server

I was trying to create shortest possible code to execute "non query" commands. Is it possible somehow to instruct to implicitly open the connection without using `conn.Open()`

```cs
public static int ExecuteNonSelect(string nonSelect)
{
     string conString = @"Data Source=...";
     int affected;

     using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(conString))
     {
          using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(nonSelect, conn))
          {
               conn.Open(); 
               affected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
               conn.Close();
          }
     }            
     return affected;
}
```

In case of the `SqlDataAdapter()` class this was not needed:

```
public static DataTable ExecuteSelect(string selectQuery) 
{
     string constring = @"Data Source=...";
     DataTable dt = new DataTable();
     using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(constring))
     {
         using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(selectQuery, conn))
         {
             da.Fill(dt); // calls ExecuteReader internally                                 
         }
     }
     return dt;
}
```

Comment: Well, yes, because `SqlDataAdapter.Fill` internally opens the connection. You don't have to explicitly call `Close()` though, that happens automatically when the connection is disposed

Comment: Yes you do. If you are looking to save lines of code though, `Close()` is called by `Dispose()` so since you have a `using` block, this is not needed. `SqlDataAdapter` also has a constructor that takes a connection string and creates a command for you, so you can avoid explicitly creating a command here. With all that being said, unless you are playing code golf, I would worry less about how long your code is, and worry more about how clear the intent is. You spend a lot more time reading code than writing it, so making it clear is much more important that saving a few lines here and there.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto nice tip to save one line!

Comment: If you are using c# 8 (or later), you can also use the `using` attribute` to save some lines. You can also return the result directly without first assigning it to a variable, so your could condense this to 5 lines: `string conString = @"Data Source=...";  using var conn = new SqlConnection(conString); using var cmd = new SqlCommand(nonSelect, conn); conn.Open(); return cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();`

Comment: @GarethD so helpful, at the moment I am using max C# 7.0 features, the one that brought tuples, but thank you for the suggestion on using keyword.

Comment: Beware of optimizing the wrong things. Fewest lines is rarely the best metric for code quality. For instance, you appear to be building a wrapper that only allows other code to submit queries as a single string - forcing open the possibility of SQL Injection not present if you let other code work with command objects and their associated parameter collections.